# Como ignorar un accesor en laravel

Tags: laravel, eloquent

tengo un problema el cual simplificaré para que sea mas entendible. Tengo los siguientes accesors en mi modelo Gastos:

```
 protected $appends = ["calendario", "cantidades"];
```

en el que **"calendario"** realiza un cálculo exorbitante. El problema es que al cargar mi página uso el atributo **"cantidades"** del modelo Gastos, pero no utilizo el atributo **"calendario"**, por lo que no requiero que se realice ese proceso ya que tarda mucho en calcularlo. ¿Hay alguna forma de traer ese atributo solo cuando lo mando a llamar?

pdt: Al cargar la página traigo todos los gastos, pero el atributo "calendario" solo lo uso en otra petición donde consulto por id. Si hay otro modo de acceder al atributo diferente al append igual me serviría

Comment: yo no termino de entender tu problema, es decir, sé que tienes esos dos accesors, pero no sé de qué tipo sean ni tampoco qué tipo de procesos hagan de acuerdo a la estructura de tus tablas

Comment: Una vez que el accessor se ha agregado al array de la propiedad `$appends` de tu modelo, se incluirá cada vez que las instancias del modelo se serialicen a array o json. Podrías simplemente quitar el que sólo utilizas eventualmente de la propiedad appends, y accederlo manualmente cuando lo necesites (`$gasto->calendario`, siendo una instancia de tu modelo el valor de la variable $gasto).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

es posible llamando a appends en el controlador, un ejemplo seria

```
//no se si los traes con get()

$gastos = Gastos::all()->setAppends(['cantidades']);
```

si esto no funciona tendrias borrar calendario de appends

```
 protected $appends = ["cantidades"];
```

y calendario llamarlo solamente en donde sea necesario con setAppends.

Answer (score 0):

Lo que pudieras hacer es obtener el accesso que dices que tarda demasiado en la query de manera dinamica, ejemplo:

```
    $data= MiModelo::get();
    foreach($data as $item) {
       $item->append('calendario');
   }
```